Получение timestamp как число при выборке всех полей
Подскажите, как сделать (MySQL) select *, но так чтобы поля timestamp пришли в виде числа?
Если отдельно поле получать, то SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) и вася-кот.. А вот если надо все поля.. Не могу сообразить..

Ну то есть в принципе никак. И лучше сразу бы отучиться использовать звезду - заодно и эта проблема решится...
